# Select2js get data from ajax source

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use Select2js in its last version. I face a problem. I use Ajax datasource, and I need to get data from the source.

Here is my code :

```
// call ajax for products
$('.product-select select').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: baseUrl +'/orders/get_products',
        processResults: function (data) {
          return {
            results: data.items
          };
        },
        select: function (data) {
            // do nothing ... 
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});

$('.product-select select').on('select2:select', function (evt) {
    // try this but evt doesn't contain data
    console.log(evt);
});
```

My datasource is :

```
[{id: 3, text: 'test', id_person: 4}, {id: 5, text: 'oooo', id_person: 5}]
```

I want to get the id_person field each time I select a row.

Comment: `.on('select2:select', function (evt, data) { /* ... * /}` - what's `data`?

Comment: It's `undefined` :(

Comment: Ah, ok. The [documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#events) suggests that the selected data is inside `evt.data`. If that's not the case, please set up a jsFiddle/stack snippet that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I don't know why, evt.data is undefined. I don't if it works for an Ajax source.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this?

```
$('.product-select select').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: baseUrl +'/orders/get_products',
        processResults: function (data) {
          return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.text,
                        id_person: item.id_person,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
          };
        },
        select: function (data) {
            // do nothing ... 
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});

$('.product-select select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  console.log(e.params.data.id_person);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Even, how can I manipulate the id_person with your code after ?